# Changing the contents of a script tag in IE 8 using YUI

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, yui

The following script works fine in Firefox but crashes in IE 8 with the error "Unknown runtime error".

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    if (Y.one('#testel') == null) {
        Y.one('head').append(Y.Node.create('<script id="testel" />'));
    }
    Y.one('#testel').set('text', 'Wish this would work in IE!');
    console.log( Y.one('#testel').get('text') );
});
```

I've played around with it in IE trying things like:

```
Y.one('#testel').set('innerHtml', 'Wish this would work in IE!');
Y.one('#testel').set('html', 'Wish this would work in IE!');
Y.one('#testel').setContents('Wish this would work in IE!');
```

with the only difference being sometimes it gives the more useful error "Unexpected call to method or property access.", which leads me to think the text of a script tag can't be changed in IE?

While searching around I found a lot of references to the above problems when dealing with table elements in IE but the work arounds in those cases didn't seem to apply to the script tag.

Is there any way to achomplish the above in IE? (I only tested this in IE 8 but I assume the problem is the same in 6,7).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a work around that solves the problem and works in IE 8 (haven't check 6,7 yet).

It seems you can only set the text when you create a script tag, so instead of trying to update the text like the code in the question, I just remove and recreate the script tag anytime I want to change the text (and this works in FF as well).

So for example:

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {

    var writeToScript = function(text) {
        if (Y.one('#asdf') != null)
            Y.one('#asdf').remove();
        Y.one('head').append(Y.Node.create("<script id='asdf'>"+ text + " </script>"));
    }

    writeToScript("Hello there!");
    console.log( Y.one('#asdf').get('innerHTML') );
    writeToScript("How are you?");
    console.log( Y.one('#asdf').get('innerHTML') );
    writeToScript("Goodbye");
    console.log( Y.one('#asdf').get('innerHTML') );
});
```

However, if anyone can explain why setting the text wasn't working as stated in the question or if you have another way to accomplish this without removing/re-adding (is this bad for performance?), please add your answer and I will up vote!! The work around makes this less urgent, but I'm still curious!!